# slideshow loading a "list" of images before snapping into correct display format

Tags: jquery

Go to [www.raviswami.com/blog](http://www.raviswami.com/blog) and click on "File_Size_Test"

This problem seems to be affecting any theme which uses the slideshow, which works fine on the theme developers self hosted demo.

I have optimized all files so they load quickly, and my server is being upgraded to increase speed / RAM, but neither seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your CSS styles refer to `.pika-image`, which is a `<div>` dynamically created by your plugin. When the page loads, the images are contained within a `<ul>` of `id="pikame"`, which is not affected by your CSS.

To get this "Flash of Unstyled Content" to go away, you'll need to add in CSS to target these images before the slideshow loads. I suggest turning off Javascript and then writing CSS to make them look the way you want.

```
#pikame {
    list-style: none;
}
```

is a good start.

Comment: thanks - not being an expert at javascript, I'm not sure where to implement these changes within the css - I've switched themes momentarily to see how the other one works, but they both have the same fault, & different .php files where the jquery is...

Comment: OK - to avoid further confusion & hopefully assist you, I'm settling on the preferred theme. Go to the same URL, but click on the leftmost thumbnail "smaller_files" to see the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked to be 100% sure but this looks like you are hiding the images with jQuery. When using the jQuery `ready()` method, it's contents don't get executed until all elements are fully loaded (generally speaking), thus it waits for all of the images to load to hide them.

Comment: This is what the theme developer suggested (at least of one of the themes) - how do I fix this in a general way so that if it occurs with another theme, I can address the issue - or is the solution going to be different for each theme ?

Comment: Add the following CSS rules and change them with jQuery/JavaScript as needed. `.attachment-full{display:none} .attachment-full:first-child{display:block}`

Comment: Thnx, but I'm not a jquery / javascript expert, so don't really know how to implement this...where does it go ? in the Header.php ?? - sample script would help which I can cut & paste / modify, if pos' - I can paste the relevant CSS, if that helps..

Comment: <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); if ( is_singular())wp_enqueue_script('script',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script.js','jquery',false);wp_enqueue_script('lazyload', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.lazyload.mini.js', 'jquery', false);wp_enqueue_script('slideshow',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', 'jquery', false);?><?php wp_head(); ?><?php if ( is_singular() ):?<scripttype="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function({jQuery('#show').after('<divid="show_nav">').cycle({fx: 'fade',speed: 60,next: '#show',timeout: 0,pager:  '#show_nav'});});</script>

Comment: That isn't CSS. That's a combination of PHP, HTML (a little bit), and jQuery. Crash course on jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works and a bit more in depth for CSS: http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp